# footer appears when re-size the screen smaller

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my footer disappear when making the screen smaller, but the footer with absolute setting keep covering up my header and my content.

How should I set my footer?

css code

```
.body {
margin: 0;
min-width: 1000px;
}
.login {
background-color: #2797E9;
border-bottom: 5px solid grey;
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
}
.nav {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1000px;
height: 40px;
border: 5px solid blue;
}
.mainleft {
width: 500px;
border: 5px solid black;
display: inline-block;
}
.mainright {
width: 500px;
border: 5px solid pink;
display: inline-block;
}
.footer {
border:5px solid green;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a media query:

```
@media (max-width:768px) {

    .footer {
        display: none;
    }

}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LGmxh/

You can adjust the width appropriately. There is also a max-height query (as well as min-height, height, width, min-width) as well as more available at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply! can max-width change it to be max height? Sorry I am a total noob

Comment: Yes, there is a max-height as well. Updated my answer